# AS3 Have whatever I type into Text Input turn into a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, input

I'm fairly new to AS3 and I want to know how would I go about having whatever is typed into a Text Input to become a variable? For example, in a text input under name if I were to type in "Jeffrey" that would become a variable and I could then use that to display "Hello, Jeffrey" or something like that with whatever the name inputted is replaced with Jeffrey.

Comment: When you say you want the input to become a variable, what do you mean?  Do you mean that a brand new variable would be spawned, and the *name* of that variable would be whatever was entered, or do you mean that an existing variable would just take the value of whatever was entered?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to implement this. One way you could do this is have a keyboard event running while input is being made. Then assuming you have the textfield created and ready for input, you have a variable that stores the textfield `text` property. So you would create your variable:

```
private var inputText:String;
```

**Next** add your listener:

```
stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
```

**Then** create the listener function, and in that function set your variable to the textfield text. In this example let's assume your textfield is called `myTextField`:

```
private function onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void {
    textInput = myTextField.text;
}
```

Now you have a variable that is storing the textfield's text every time a key is pressed.

Whenever you are done with the input, remove the listener from the stage:

```
stage.removeEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
```

Now there is also an alternative way. You can attach a `TEXT_INPUT` event to the textfield and capture the input that way, like so:

```
myTextField.addEventListener( TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput ); 

public function onInput( e:TextEvent ):void { 
    inputString = myTextField.text; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

**1: Define "something that is typed into a TextInput".**

The reason for this is that each thing is typed in one keystroke at a time.  This is important, because for the word "Jeffrey", you have several different things that get typed into there:

```
J
Je
Jef
Jeff
Jeffr
Jeffre
Jeffrey
```

You probably don't want all of those turned into variables, but ActionScript 3.0 will more-or-less think of those as all separate inputs.  Somehow you have to distinguish "Jeffrey" from all the rest.  Usually this is done by making the user click a Submit button or tab off the TextInput or something, but you'll have to decide.

**2: Add a dictionary variable to your class and use the input as one of its keys:**

```
private var myDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
```

Whenever the program decides that the user has finished typing something into the TextInput (like in a Submit button's click handler), just do this:

```
myDict[myTextInput.text] = new Object(); // or whatever value you want
```

So let's say the user entered the value "Jeffrey".  Then you could come back later and access what is effectively a variable by that name:

```
myDict[myTextInput.text] = 5; // myTextInput.text == "Jeffrey"
.
.
.
trace(myDict["Jeffrey"]); // output is "5"
trace(myDict.Jeffrey); // output is "5"
trace(myDict[myTextInput.text]); // output is "5" if myTextInput.text is the same
```

Effectively rolling back an earlier edit, just go ahead and use a `Dictionary`, not an `Object`.  If the user types in certain things like "12345", things will just go better if you use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Interesting way to go about it. But using a dictionary seems like overkill, especially compared to a text input event and updating a single variable.

Comment: Looks like we interpreted the question differently.  Looking at the question, he could've meant either one, it looks like.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I can see how that could have multiple interpretations.